# Excel File corrupted after changing file extension programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the below code that changes a .xls Excel file to a .xlsx format(Excel 2007 and above), but the resulting .xlsx file is corrupted. It can't be read programmatically in c# nor can it be opened in windows Explorer.

The original .xls file has some quite a number of macro functions.

```
tring fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
fileName = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/ProcessedFiles/", fileName));
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".xlsx"));
```

Comment: You are just changing the extension, you aren't doing anything to the actual content of the file (at least not in the code here). So when you try to open your .xlsx-file it will still contain the old .xls-format.

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren, any idea how to change the format?

Comment: That would require parsing the old format and then saving it as the new one. Have a look at http://npoi.codeplex.com/ to help you with that.